# Equivalent of C# Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes in php

Tags: c#, php

I have an example in C# and have to write the same in PHP.

```
request = request.Replace(sign, string.Empty);

byte[] sha1Request;
using (var shaM = new SHA1Managed())
{
    sha1Request = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request));
}
log.InfoFormat($"request={request}. sha1Request={Convert.ToBase64String(sha1Request)}. Sign={sign}", request, Convert.ToBase64String(sha1Request));
var pubKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)FrontInterface.GetCertificate(checkFrontCertificateCod.Value).PublicKey.Key;
var isValid = pubKey.VerifyData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(sha1Request)), new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), Convert.FromBase64String(sign));
if (!isValid)
{
    throw new Exception("Wrong digital sign");
}
```

So, I may not convert string to bytes in php and line `sha1Request = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request));`
will be in PHP: `sha1Request =sha1(request, true);`
Am I rigth? If not, please help me to convert in PHP this line.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is neither Python nor PHP…

Comment: May be it is Java?

Comment: I'd rather guess C# or something, but I don't know. In a nutshell though, this language appears to have a string type and a byte type, and must convert between the two. PHP only has a byte type essentially (though it calls it `string`), so there's no need for this step in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Note that sha1 should not really be used any more for security relevant applications, it is out of date.

C# Version:

```
string text = "<Hällo World>";

byte[] sha1;
using (var shaM = new SHA1Managed())
{
    sha1 = shaM.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
}
string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1);

Console.Write(encoded);
```

PHP Version:

```
$text = "<Hällo World>";

// Encode as UTF8 if necessary (May not be necessary if string is already utf-8)
$text = utf8_encode($text);

// Calculate SHA1 
$sha1 = sha1($text, TRUE);

// Convert to Base64
$encoded = base64_encode($sha1);

echo($encoded);
```

Both versions should output

> 1nSiStZRa/quRru7Sqe+ejupqfs=

Note that the call to `utf8_encode` should only be there if the string you work with is not actually already encoded in utf8.

If the string is a literal in a *.php file, this depends on how the file is stored on the disk. (What character set it uses).

If the string is retrieved from a web request or from a database or from reading a file, this also depends on what character set the web form, the database or the external file use.